# does BlockingQueue need synchronized?

Tags: java

could you help me?
Is this necessery for BlockingQueue, when I want to be sure that only one thread modify queue?:

BlockingQueue queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(1024);

Collections=Collections.synchronizedCollection(queue); <--- is this necessary?

Comment: According to documentation it states __Note that a BlockingQueue can safely be used with multiple producers and multiple consumers.__ and again __BlockingQueue implementations are thread-safe. All queuing methods achieve their effects atomically using internal locks or other forms of concurrency control.__

Answer (score 2):

Since `BlockingQueue` is thread safe, you do not need to synchronize its accesses: the concurrency is handled by the class itself.

The [`BlockingQueue` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) states:

> BlockingQueue implementations are thread-safe.

It also provides a producer - consumer example.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation: "BlockingQueue implementations are thread-safe."
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

Answer (score 0):

No,you don't need to `synchronize` it explicitly.

Internally it use's `ReentrantLock` to guard the access,

```
    final ReentrantLock lock;
    /** Condition for waiting takes */
    private final Condition notEmpty;
    /** Condition for waiting puts */
    private final Condition notFull;
```

See [Source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.java)
For ex:-

```
public boolean offer(E e) {
        checkNotNull(e);
        final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
        lock.lock();
        try {
            //
            //
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
```